# Knex экранирование кавычек

Tags: json, node.js, knex.js

Использую данный модуль в node.js. При запросе на получение данных (строка json) из бд, получаю экранированные слеши:

```
{"selector":"a[class=\\"xf-product-title__link js-product__title\\"]","site":"https:\\/\\/www.ya.ru\\/catalog\\/kartinki\\/nasha/"}
```

а нужно получать в том виде, в котором хранится:

```
{"selector":"a[class=\"xf-product-title__link js-product__title\"]","site":"https://www.ya.ru/catalog/kartinki/nasha/"}
```

как отключать экранирование?